# Excel, get data from matrix

Tags: excel, matrix

I have a matrix table in excel, from which I need to get data, with two parameters.

Here's my matrix table:
[image: Matrix Table]

Now, I want to enter manually Parameter 1 and Parameter 2 as numbers in two fields:
[image: Choose parameters]

With the values 900 and 2000 it should get the number **283** from the matrix.

How can I do that? I tried at least 5 different variations (german excel) with INDEX and VERGLEICH (MATCH), or with SVERWEIS (VLOOKUP) with VERGLEICH (MATCH).

Here's my latest one:

```
 =SVERWEIS(B55;'table_2'!B41:AO41;VERGLEICH(C55;'table_2'!A5:A40;0);FALSCH)
```

In this code, B55 is Parameter 1 and C55 is Parameter 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this formula:

```
=SVERWEIS(C55;'table_2'!A5:AO40;VERGLEICH(B55;'table_2'!B41:AO41;0)+1;FALSCH)
```

Comment: It works perfectly. Thanks.
Not I need to round up the parameter numbers. If I enter 920 into B55, it should round it up to 1000. With the function `RUNDEN(B55;-2)` it round's it down to 900. Is there a better round function?

Comment: Done. Didn't know there's a function named AUFRUNDEN (round up only). Thanks again.